# How do I programatically add a button to a Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

Okay, so I have my `LinearLayout` inside of a `ScrollView` which I have defined in my xml layout as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container" />
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I then access this `LinearLayout` with this code which is contained in an `Activity` and attempt to add a button to it:

```
var container = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.container);
var myButton = new Button(this) {
        Text = "Button Text"
     };
myButton .Click += delegate { /*Do stuff*/ };
container.AddView(myButton, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent));
```

My issue is that the button does not show up when I debug my application. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: That's why I put xamarin as a tag...

Comment: yeah yeah I know, as far as the logic goes, it's correct, try this container.AddView(myButton);

Answer (score 0):

I guess there was a problem with visual studio. I closed and reopened it and the button seemed to show up. Weird...